# How to convert string value into date in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want convert string value into date in my project because I am fetching XML value from web. In XML file I get weather condition and there all value in this weather condition I get current date but my forecastcondition is not come in date it comes in string value, like this:

> friday saturday and sunday

Like this value are come in my forecast condition day this string value come in `Day_of_week [Day_of_week]` means it shows like this:

> friday,saturday,sunday

How can I convert this string value with date?

This is my controller class.m file

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TWeatherCell *cell =(TWeatherCell *) [MyTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell_%d", indexPath.row]];
    if (cell == nil) {
        //cell = [[[TWeatherCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell = [[[TWeatherCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell_%d", indexPath.row]] autorelease];
    }
        //ForecastCondition *cond=[forecastcond objectAtIndex:0];
    ForecastCondition *cond1=[forecastcond objectAtIndex:1];
    ForecastCondition *cond2=[forecastcond objectAtIndex:2];
    ForecastCondition *cond3=[forecastcond objectAtIndex:3];

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date]; // some valid date, let's say today is thursdaya
    NSDate *thursday = [today dateWithTimeInterval:1 *ONE_DAY sinceDate:cond1.Dayofweek];
    NSDate *friday = [today dateWithTimeInterval:2 * ONE_DAY sinceDate:cond2.Dayofweek];
    NSDate *saturday = [today dateWithTimeInterval:3 * ONE_DAY sinceDate:cond3.Dayofweek];
    if ([currentcond.Icon isEqualToString:@"http://\n"])
    {
        cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listIcon-H.png"];
    }
    else {
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentcond.Icon]];       
        NSLog(@"this is image from server:%@",imageData);
        cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        [imageData release];
    }
    NSDateFormatter *date_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]; 
    [date_formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"]; 
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
    NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
            NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentcond.Icon]];
            NSLog(@"this is image from server:%@",imageData);
            cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            [imageData release];

    cell.reportdate.text = _forecastInfo.CurrentDateTime;
    cell.conditionname.text = currentcond.Condition;
    cell.twotemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Temp:%@/%@",currentcond.Tempf,currentcond.Tempf];
    cell.twodirection.text = currentcond.WindCondition;
    cell.humidity.text = currentcond.Humidity;

    break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);

            cell.reportdate.text = cond1.Dayofweek;
            cell.conditionname.text = cond1.Condition;
            cell.twotemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Temp:%@/%@",cond1.Low,cond1.High];
            //NSDateFormatter *date_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]; 
//          [date_formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"]; 

            //[cond.Dayofweek dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(60*60*24)*1];
            //NSDate *date1 = [date_formatter dateFromString:cond.Dayofweek]; 
            //NSDate *= NSDate *date1 ;
            //NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
            //NSString *strDate = [date_formatter stringFromDate:date1]; 


            break;
        case 2:

            NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
            cell.reportdate.text = cond2.Dayofweek;
            cell.conditionname.text = cond2.Condition;
            cell.twotemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Temp:%@/%@",cond2.Low,cond2.High];
            break;
        case 3:
            NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
            cell.reportdate.text = cond3.Dayofweek;
            cell.conditionname.text = cond3.Condition;
            cell.twotemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Temp:%@/%@",cond3.Low,cond3.High];
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Out of Range ",indexPath.row);
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: PLEASE format your question properly.. and post only the relevant code not the entire method...

Comment: +10 to @lukya. Ok, only +1 but imagine I voted 9 more times afterwards ;)

Comment: @perception:same from ma side too (-_^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gather that your problem is that future dates are coming in as "Thursday", "Friday", ...?

Basically, you need to convert that text to a day-of-week number (simplest approach is an "if ladder", though if you want to be locale-sensitive you can use a more complex scheme).  Then figure out today's day-of-week number and subtract that from the first number.  If the result is *negative*, add 7.  (If the result is zero, it may mean that it refers to today, or it may mean it refers to a week from today -- if you want the latter, add 7 if the result is *zero or negative*.)  Then, to compute the date represented by the input day of the week, add the above computed result multiplied times ONE_DAY to the current date.

### More detail

You know what an "if ladder" is, of course:

```
if ([day isEqualToString:@"Sunday"]) {
    dayNumber = 1;
}
else if ([day isEqualToString:@"Monday"]) {
    dayNumber = 2;
}
else if ([day isEqualToString:@"Tuesday"]) {
....
```

To get the day of week from the current date use something like:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
NSInteger todayNumber = [components weekday];
```

Subtract todayNumber from dayNumber.  If the result is negative, add 7 to the result.  That value then tells you how many days in the future "day" is, and from that you can calculate it's date.

Comment: yes u right my problem this future dates are coming in as "Thursday", "Friday",  only  how to do can u explan in code please what i past please explan in my code

Comment: please help me on this how to do it not any local it come from server so ho to that

Comment: actually i am getting confused in the  calculation part on how to figure out today's day-of-week number and subtract that from the first numb

Comment: What's confusing?  You plug in your "today" value in the second line of the three, and get the day-of-week number out as "todayNumber".  You subtract because if today is Tuesday it's day number is 3 (Sunday is 1) and if the other day is "Thursday" your if ladder will have assigned that a value of 5.  5 minus 3 gives you 2 days difference.  If, on the other hand, the other day was Sunday, you compute 1 minus 3 and get negative 2.  So, since it's a negative number, add 7 to get 5 days difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/setTimeStyle%3a) to convert between `NSString` and `NSDate`

Answer (score 0):

you can use "datefromstring" for ur problem.
here i've an example for this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy "];
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:YourDate_String];
 NSLog(@"Date: %@",date1);
[dateFormatter release];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @surykant what i have to pass YourDate_String];i have to pass my value mean this cond1.Dayofweek u said this value i have to pass

Comment: @rani u want a to convert a date which was in string earlier.. that string is YourDate_String.  also set dd-MM-yyyy to setdateformat,as ur string is in this format only

Comment: what u r getting. and what string u r passing, let me know, then only i can do something

Comment: i am doing this NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy "]; NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:cond1.Dayofweek]; NSLog(@"Date: %@",date1); [dateFormatter release]; cell.reportdate.text = date1 ;

Comment: what u r getting in the string " cond1.Dayofweek ".

Comment: i get in this string friday ,and sturday and sunday this value i get so i want this future day i want to convert into date how to do

Comment: ok, now i got it, u r not passing date as string, only weekday as string.and after that u want to know date from that weekday, isn't??

Comment: Then u have to go ahead with if..elseladder. check for every condition then pass ur required value.hope u will get it.Just u need to run a if..else ladder with a proper value.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease]; 
[df setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"]; 
NSDate* date = [df dateFromString:@"date string"];

NSLog(@"Converted date is %@",date);
```

Comment: my string value is come in Day_of_week so how can i pass this value to con vert inti date my value on this variable cond1.Dayofweek please help me on this