# iPhone : Unable to convert date from string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, nsdate

I am trying to convert string into NSDate using following code.

```
NSString *old = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"OLD_DATE"];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *oldDate = [formatter dateFromString:old];
NSLog(@"Old Date : %@",oldDate);
```

I am setting `OLD_DATE` as following :

```
NSDate *oldDate = [NSDate date];
NSString *old = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",oldDate] retain];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:old forKey:@"OLD_DATE"];
```

But I am getting null in the `NSLog(@"Old Date : %@",oldDate);` :(

I found many similar [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775396/how-to-convert-string-value-into-date-in-iphone) with the same code and works fine for them.

So what could be problem with my code ?

Comment: Can you confirm that NSString `old` actually contains a value in the right format or is it possible that the user defaults did not save your value correctly?

Comment: No. Its storing value in both : NSString and also in UserDefaults.

Comment: Date Formate : dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't covert the date to string:

```
NSDate *oldDate = [NSDate date];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:oldDate forKey:@"OLD_DATE"];
```

To read out the date just:

```
NSDate *old = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"OLD_DATE"];
```

There really should not be any reason to concert the date to a string before saving to in the `NSUserDefaults`.

But if you want to concert the string back to a date you will need the correct format.
A NSDate descrption would be something like `2011-11-11 12:58:36 +0000`

```
NSString *old = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"OLD_DATE"];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];
NSDate *oldDate = [formatter dateFromString:old];
NSLog(@"Old Date : %@",oldDate);
```

Comment: I have already tried that. Its crashing my app when i do : `double diff = [old timeIntervalSince1970];

Comment: Sorry there was an other misstake in your code, use `objectForKey` not `valueForKey`. Also make sure you just save a `NSDate` not a `NSString`. I do it all the time in my apps and it will work.