# NSDate from NSString gives null result

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am using following code to generate `NSDate -> NSString`

```
+(NSString *)getCurrentTime
{
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:MM:SS a"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    NSString* str =[dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
    [dateFormatter release];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
    return str;
}
```

everything is fine in above code. I am using above code to store string in Database. Now while retrieving that string gives me `NULL`. Following is my code to retrieve date in specific format

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:MM:SS a"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    NSDate *dt =[dateFormatter dateFromString:crdInfo.swipeTime];
    NSLog(@"Date : %@",dt);
    [dateFormatter release];
```

How should I retrieve or store with particular format?? My crdInfo.swipeTime is retrieving String propertly...

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava: but not working...

Comment: Check the value of crdInfo.swipeTime

Comment: I already checked that... and that is returning me value...

Comment: I think that problem is in your "hh:MM:SS a". Personally I use "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ". IIrc "MM" stands for month and not for minutes. I'd also use "HH" instead of "hh" for 24h format. And seconds are "ss" and not "SS". Don't know what "a" is for, but I guess it's ok. Hope it helps

Comment: date format should be same at time of storing and retrieving

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094238/iphone-unable-to-convert-date-from-string  and try some google

Comment: @Devang: Yes this question is duplicate to many other questions on SO but in my case this is not working and the link that you provided is somehow different. So kindly please suggest me solution? or atleast point out where i am wrong...

Comment: @DShah: Try to format it to `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a`. You wrote `dd-MM-yyyy hh:MM:SS a` where `MM` in `hh:MM:SS` gives month which is unrecognized in this format and there is no point writing upercase SS for seconds.

Comment: I think you are retrieving only time from the date not the full date !!!

Comment: yes i m not retrieving full date.. i just want time with hh:mm:ss am/pm format...

Comment: @Narayana: +1 for your suggestion... thanx...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Narayana suggested you need to retrieve the date with same format as you have stored. Retrieve it as below : -

```
    NSDateFormatter *reDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [reDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:MM:SS a"];
    [reDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    NSDate *dt = [reDateFormatter dateFromString:str];
    NSLog(@"The Date : %@",dt);

    [reDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:MM:SS a"];
    NSString *currentTime = [reDateFormatter stringFromDate:dt];
    NSLog(@"%@",currentTime);
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

First off, why not just store the NSDate object or epoch timestamp? This will give you much more flexibility in the future.

Now to your problem, I suspect it is due to your configuration of the NSDateFormatter, you're saving it in one format and trying to convert it to a date using a different format. Make the formats the same and try again. If you want to display it differently than it is stored you're likely going to need to convert it to and NSDate using the stored format and then again use another date formatter to get it in the format you want it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try to format it to `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss` a.

You wrote `dd-MM-yyyy hh:MM:SS` a where `MM` in `hh:MM:SS` gives month which is unrecognized in this format and there is no point writing upercase SS for seconds

Hope you understand it.

Comment: I think he wants to retrieve only time from the date.

Comment: @Parth Bhatt: I had done some demo apps where i tried using all combinations of upper and smaller case... But from my test results i found that it only Matters with **HH** and **hh** only when you are not mentioning **a** part i.e. AM/PM part. So i solved that issue in that Demo app. But I tried that way also and its not working... anyways...Thanks and suggest if u have different idea...